# interpolate data to triangular mesh

Tags: python-3.x, interpolation, triangular, spatial-interpolation

There are a lot of questions (and answers) available for people interpolating unstructured data to structured output. solutions to which include mesh grid or bivariate splines. However I'm looking for the inverse. How do I interpolate structured data to an unstructured (delaulany) triangular  (quickly)?

The data i have are loaded with meshio as part of the pygmsh.

```
import meshio as mio
data = mio.read(fname)

data.cells['vertex'].shape
Out[128]: (2906, 1)
data.cells['triangle'].shape
Out[129]: (213898, 3)

plt.figure()
plt.tripcolor(data.points[:, 0], data.points[:, 1], -data.points[:, 2])
plt.triplot(data.points[:, 0], data.points[:, 1], 'k.', ms=2)
```

shows the below plot [image: shoreline data].  I have new data that I'm trying to update on this triangular mesh.  I was planning on interpolating the values of the regularly structured data to the same points in space, then updating the values of the triangular mesh.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I've found to this is [Python: interpolating in a triangular mesh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118039/python-interpolating-in-a-triangular-mesh)

Working off of that answer and expanding with examples.

```
newBathy['lon'].shape
Out[154]: (1040, 271)
newBathy['lat'].shape
Out[155]: (1040, 271)
newBathy['elevation'].shape
Out[156]: (1040, 271)
#I have to flatten so i don't get a shape error 
triObj = tri.Triangulation(newBathy['lon'].flatten(), newBathy['lat'].flatten()) 
ftri = tri.LinearTriInterpolator(triObj, newBathy['elevation'].flatten())
newZs = ftri(data.points[:, 0], data.points[:, 1])
```

This leaves me with data only in a small portion of the known domain, but i can updated the non-masked values in the newZs from those of the `data.points([:,3])`.  Haven't quite figured out the best way, as the cubic interpolation takes a while and makes my computer sound like a spaceship.  The linear clearly works, but could be nicer looking.

[image]